# Proof of identity using polynomial operator and commutators

Tags: polynomials, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

Suppose *x* is a real number, and $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ are two non-commuting operators.

A polynomial operator is defined by

$$g(\hat{B}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \hat{B}^n,$$
where $a_n$ are real numbers.

If [$\hat{A}$ , $\hat{B}$] = c, where c is a complex number, prove that

$$exp(x\hat{A})g(\hat{B})exp(-x\hat{A}) = g(\hat{B} + cx).$$

A previous proof yielded the taylor expansion of a similar expression, which led me to believe it could be the key, thus i started at

$$exp(x\hat{A})g(\hat{B})exp(-x\hat{A}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty [\hat{A},g(\hat{B})]_n \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

Here, $[\hat{A} , \hat{B}]_n$ := $[\hat{A},[\hat{A},\hat{B}]]_{n-1}$, describes the nested commutator, with $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]_0 := \hat{B}.$

Sadly, I could not make it work as of now. Am I missing an obvious or simple solution? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially there!

Observe $\hat A/c$ acts like a *derivative operator* on powers of $\hat B$, and so $g(\hat B)$ as well, 
$$
[\hat A, g(\hat B)]= c g^{(1)}(\hat B), \qquad \Longrightarrow \\
[\hat A, g(\hat B)]_n= c^n g^{(n)} (\hat B),
$$
where the superscript in parenthesis denotes number of derivatives; 
so that, substituting in your final (Duhamel) expression readily yields the Taylor expansion at $\hat B$,
$$\exp(x\hat{A})g(\hat{B})\exp(-x\hat{A}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty [\hat{A},g(\hat{B})]_n ~ \frac{x^n}{n!}\\
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty g^{(n)} (\hat B) ~\frac{c^n  x^n}{n!} = g(\hat B + cx)
    ~  .$$

(Historically, this was Baker's minority contribution to the CBH expansion algorithm.)